Classes missing from apk
I'm trying to build a project and run it on Android simulator.
I can build the APK without error.
Not only that, but I can start the app and use it, but at some point I face the below exception and app crashes.
It looks like some classes are not part of the APK.
The one at the bottom Didn't find class "org.w3c.dom.events.EventTarget" on path is part of the JRE so it's not an external dependency.
I'm targeting Android SDK 32 for now as I just want to make it work before upgrading.
Do you have any idea what to do?
Thanks
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483): An error occurred while executing a task on the OperationQueue.
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/xerces/dom/CoreDocumentImpl;
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.setFeature(Unknown Source:126)
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  at c.e.a.f.d.j.x(:42)
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  at com.xxx.scratch.c.p.b.F(:200)
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  at com.xxx.scratch.c.p.b$c.run(:126)
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  at com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a$a.run(:34)
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:487)
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.dom.CoreDocumentImpl
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  ... 10 more
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/xerces/dom/ParentNode;
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  ... 10 more
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.dom.ParentNode
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  ... 10 more
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/xerces/dom/ChildNode;
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  ... 10 more
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.dom.ChildNode
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  ... 10 more
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/xerces/dom/NodeImpl;
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  ... 10 more
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.dom.NodeImpl
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  ... 10 more
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/w3c/dom/events/EventTarget;
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  ... 10 more
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.w3c.dom.events.EventTarget" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~j6mpgpLbTOaBmECGO2VDdg==/com.xxx.android-eY9BUVhcBhZ_6-C0HJGejA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~j6mpgpLbTOaBmECGO2VDdg==/com.xxx.android-eY9BUVhcBhZ_6-C0HJGejA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~j6mpgpLbTOaBmECGO2VDdg==/com.xxx.android-eY9BUVhcBhZ_6-C0HJGejA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
05-31 18:47:44.426 E/com.xxx.scratch.c.s.a(30483):  ... 10 more



it may be some files are removed by proguard or R8?

I tried setting minifyEnabled false and I still get the same result.

I would compare the sizes of the debug and the release versions, it still may be removing some of the classes

None of the release or the debug version are working.
The debug crashes with the above stacktrace.
The release version crashes too, but I have R8 warning about those missing classes.

try maybe excluding the entire package, just to test -keep public class yourpackage.yourPackage.youpackage.**

I don't know why, but I had to add the following dependency to build.gradle to make it work.
implementation 'xml-apis:xml-apis:1.4.01'

